# Iterate through selected gridview cells by row index

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

I am using a GridView control to display some data and I need to programatically change the values of the selected cells. When I iterate through the selected cells collection, it is sorted in the order which you selected the cells in. For example, the row indexes may be 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2. I want to edit all the cells with row index 1 before I move on to 2.

Comment: Is it standard selected cells collection? IS it built in GridView or third party like telerik, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to iterate through the SelectedCells collection of a Windows Forms DataGridView in Row Index order.

I don't have a real setup to test this right now, but you could try something like this:

```
var q = dataGridView1.SelectedCells.OfType<DataGridViewCell>().OrderBy(x => x.RowIndex);
```

You can then "foreach" over q

Cheers

Comment: Thank you very much! I am still trying to get the hang of the lambda expression wizardry. I modified it to sort by columns as well:

`var q = dataGridView1.SelectedCells.OfType<DataGridViewCell>().OrderBy(x => x.ColumnIndex).OrderBy(x => x.RowIndex);`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just for each over the rows, and have an inner for each loop to go through the columns?